# Как русифицировать stb_easy_font?

Tags: c++, opengl, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек, русификация

Разрабатываю игру на С++ и OpenGL, нужно создать менюшку, всё работает, кроме одной детали - не отображает русский текст. использую библиотеку stb_easy_font.
и собственно вопрос - есть ли похожие библиотеки, но с поддержкой русского языка, или способ русифицировать данную библиотеку?

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include "menu.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);

void Init()
{
    Menu_AddButton("sss", 10, 10, 100, 30, 2);
    Menu_AddButton("aaa", 10, 50, 100, 30, 2);
    Menu_AddButton("Опции", 10, 90, 100, 30, 2);
    Menu_AddButton("О проекте", 10, 130, 100, 30, 2);
    Menu_AddButton("Выход", 10, 170, 100, 30, 2);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;
    float theta = 0.0f;

    /* register window class */
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    /* create main window */
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                          "GLSample",
                          "OpenGL Sample",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          500,
                          500,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

     RECT rct;
    GetClientRect(hwnd,&rct);
    glOrtho(0,rct.right, rct.bottom, 0, 1, -1);

    Init();
    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glPushMatrix();

            Menu_ShowMenu();

            glPopMatrix();

            SwapBuffers(hDC);

            theta += 1.0f;
            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
         Menu_MouseMove(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            Menu_MouseDown();
        break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            Menu_MouseUp();
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

menu.c

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stb_easy_font.h"

#include "menu.h"

#define nameLen 20

typedef struct{
    char name[nameLen];
    float vert[8];
    char isHower, isDown;
    float buffer[50 * nameLen];
    int num_quads;
    float textPosX,textPosY,textScale;
} TBtn;
TBtn *btn = 0;
int btnCnt = 0;

float mouseX,mouseY;

int Menu_AddButton(char *name, float x, float y, float width, float height, float textScale)
{
    btnCnt++;
    btn = realloc(btn, sizeof(btn[0]) * btnCnt);

    snprintf(btn[btnCnt-1].name, nameLen, "%s", name);
    float *vert = btn[btnCnt-1].vert;
    vert[0] = vert[6] = x;
    vert[2] = vert[4] = x + width;
    vert[1] = vert[3] = y;
    vert[5] = vert[7] = y + height;
    btn[btnCnt-1].isHower = 0;
    btn[btnCnt-1].isDown = 0;

    TBtn *b = btn + btnCnt - 1;
    b->num_quads = stb_easy_font_print(0,0, name, 0, b->buffer, sizeof(b->buffer));
    b->textPosX = x + (width - stb_easy_font_width(name) * textScale) / 2.0;
    b->textPosY = y + (height - stb_easy_font_height(name) * textScale) / 2.0;;
    b->textPosY += textScale * 2;
    b->textScale = textScale;

    return btnCnt - 1;
}

void ShowButton(int buttonId)
{
TBtn btn1 = btn[buttonId];
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, btn1.vert);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    if(btn1.isDown) glColor3f(0.2, 1, 0.2);
    else if (btn1.isHower) glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 1);
    else glColor3f(0.6,0.6,0.8);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glLineWidth(1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,4);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 glPushMatrix();
  glColor3f(0,0,0);
  glTranslatef(btn1.textPosX, btn1.textPosY, 0);
  glScalef(btn1.textScale, btn1.textScale, 1);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 16, btn1.buffer);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, btn1.num_quads*4);
  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 glPopMatrix();
}
void Menu_ShowMenu()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < btnCnt; i++)
        ShowButton(i);
}

char isCoordInButton(int buttonId, float x, float y)
{
    float *vert = btn[buttonId].vert;
    return (x > vert[0]) && (y > vert[1]) &&(x < vert[4]) && (y < vert[5]);
}

int Menu_MouseMove(float x, float y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    int moveBtn = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < btnCnt; i++)
        if (isCoordInButton(i, mouseX, mouseY))
    {
        btn[i].isHower = 1;
        moveBtn = i;
    }
    else
    {
        btn[i].isHower = 0;
        btn[i].isDown = 0;
    }
    return moveBtn;
}
int Menu_MouseDown()
{
    int downBtn = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < btnCnt; i++)
        if (isCoordInButton(i, mouseX, mouseY))
    {
        btn[i].isDown = 1;
        downBtn = i;
    }
    return downBtn;
}
void Menu_MouseUp()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < btnCnt; i++)
        btn[i].isDown = 0;
}
```

menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H_INCLUDED
#define MENU_H_INCLUDED

int Menu_AddButton(char *name, float x, float y, float width, float height, float textScale);
void Menu_ShowMenu();

int Menu_MouseMove(float x, float y);
int Menu_MouseDown();
void Menu_MouseUp();

#endif
```

stb_easu_font.h

```
    // stb_easy_font.h - v1.1 - bitmap font for 3D rendering - public domain
// Sean Barrett, Feb 2015
//
//    Easy-to-deploy,
//    reasonably compact,
//    extremely inefficient performance-wise,
//    crappy-looking,
//    ASCII-only,
//    bitmap font for use in 3D APIs.
//
// Intended for when you just want to get some text displaying
// in a 3D app as quickly as possible.
//
// Doesn't use any textures, instead builds characters out of quads.
//
// DOCUMENTATION:
//
//   int stb_easy_font_width(char *text)
//   int stb_easy_font_height(char *text)
//
//      Takes a string and returns the horizontal size and the
//      vertical size (which can vary if 'text' has newlines).
//
//   int stb_easy_font_print(float x, float y,
//                           char *text, unsigned char color[4],
//                           void *vertex_buffer, int vbuf_size)
//
//      Takes a string (which can contain '\n') and fills out a
//      vertex buffer with renderable data to draw the string.
//      Output data assumes increasing x is rightwards, increasing y
//      is downwards.
//
//      The vertex data is divided into quads, i.e. there are four
//      vertices in the vertex buffer for each quad.
//
//      The vertices are stored in an interleaved format:
//
//         x:float
//         y:float
//         z:float
//         color:uint8[4]
//
//      You can ignore z and color if you get them from elsewhere
//      This format was chosen in the hopes it would make it
//      easier for you to reuse existing vertex-buffer-drawing code.
//
//      If you pass in NULL for color, it becomes 255,255,255,255.
//
//      Returns the number of quads.
//
//      If the buffer isn't large enough, it will truncate.
//      Expect it to use an average of ~270 bytes per character.
//
//      If your API doesn't draw quads, build a reusable index
//      list that allows you to render quads as indexed triangles.
//
//   void stb_easy_font_spacing(float spacing)
//
//      Use positive values to expand the space between characters,
//      and small negative values (no smaller than -1.5) to contract
//      the space between characters.
//
//      E.g. spacing = 1 adds one "pixel" of spacing between the
//      characters. spacing = -1 is reasonable but feels a bit too
//      compact to me; -0.5 is a reasonable compromise as long as
//      you're scaling the font up.
//
// LICENSE
//
//   See end of file for license information.
//
// VERSION HISTORY
//
//   (2020-02-02)  1.1   make everything static so can compile it in more than one src file
//   (2017-01-15)  1.0   space character takes same space as numbers; fix bad spacing of 'f'
//   (2016-01-22)  0.7   width() supports multiline text; add height()
//   (2015-09-13)  0.6   #include <math.h>; updated license
//   (2015-02-01)  0.5   First release
//
// CONTRIBUTORS
//
//   github:vassvik    --  bug report
//   github:podsvirov  --  fix multiple definition errors

#if 0
// SAMPLE CODE:
//
//    Here's sample code for old OpenGL; it's a lot more complicated
//    to make work on modern APIs, and that's your problem.
//
void print_string(float x, float y, char *text, float r, float g, float b)
{
  static char buffer[99999]; // ~500 chars
  int num_quads;

  num_quads = stb_easy_font_print(x, y, text, NULL, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

  glColor3f(r,g,b);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 16, buffer);
  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, num_quads*4);
  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
#endif

#ifndef INCLUDE_STB_EASY_FONT_H
#define INCLUDE_STB_EASY_FONT_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

static struct stb_easy_font_info_struct {
    unsigned char advance;
    unsigned char h_seg;
    unsigned char v_seg;
} stb_easy_font_charinfo[96] = {
    {  6,  0,  0 },  {  3,  0,  0 },  {  5,  1,  1 },  {  7,  1,  4 },
    {  7,  3,  7 },  {  7,  6, 12 },  {  7,  8, 19 },  {  4, 16, 21 },
    {  4, 17, 22 },  {  4, 19, 23 },  { 23, 21, 24 },  { 23, 22, 31 },
    { 20, 23, 34 },  { 22, 23, 36 },  { 19, 24, 36 },  { 21, 25, 36 },
    {  6, 25, 39 },  {  6, 27, 43 },  {  6, 28, 45 },  {  6, 30, 49 },
    {  6, 33, 53 },  {  6, 34, 57 },  {  6, 40, 58 },  {  6, 46, 59 },
    {  6, 47, 62 },  {  6, 55, 64 },  { 19, 57, 68 },  { 20, 59, 68 },
    { 21, 61, 69 },  { 22, 66, 69 },  { 21, 68, 69 },  {  7, 73, 69 },
    {  9, 75, 74 },  {  6, 78, 81 },  {  6, 80, 85 },  {  6, 83, 90 },
    {  6, 85, 91 },  {  6, 87, 95 },  {  6, 90, 96 },  {  7, 92, 97 },
    {  6, 96,102 },  {  5, 97,106 },  {  6, 99,107 },  {  6,100,110 },
    {  6,100,115 },  {  7,101,116 },  {  6,101,121 },  {  6,101,125 },
    {  6,102,129 },  {  7,103,133 },  {  6,104,140 },  {  6,105,145 },
    {  7,107,149 },  {  6,108,151 },  {  7,109,155 },  {  7,109,160 },
    {  7,109,165 },  {  7,118,167 },  {  6,118,172 },  {  4,120,176 },
    {  6,122,177 },  {  4,122,181 },  { 23,124,182 },  { 22,129,182 },
    {  4,130,182 },  { 22,131,183 },  {  6,133,187 },  { 22,135,191 },
    {  6,137,192 },  { 22,139,196 },  {  6,144,197 },  { 22,147,198 },
    {  6,150,202 },  { 19,151,206 },  { 21,152,207 },  {  6,155,209 },
    {  3,160,210 },  { 23,160,211 },  { 22,164,216 },  { 22,165,220 },
    { 22,167,224 },  { 22,169,228 },  { 21,171,232 },  { 21,173,233 },
    {  5,178,233 },  { 22,179,234 },  { 23,180,238 },  { 23,180,243 },
    { 23,180,248 },  { 22,189,248 },  { 22,191,252 },  {  5,196,252 },
    {  3,203,252 },  {  5,203,253 },  { 22,210,253 },  {  0,214,253 },
};

static unsigned char stb_easy_font_hseg[214] = {
   97,37,69,84,28,51,2,18,10,49,98,41,65,25,81,105,33,9,97,1,97,37,37,36,
    81,10,98,107,3,100,3,99,58,51,4,99,58,8,73,81,10,50,98,8,73,81,4,10,50,
    98,8,25,33,65,81,10,50,17,65,97,25,33,25,49,9,65,20,68,1,65,25,49,41,
    11,105,13,101,76,10,50,10,50,98,11,99,10,98,11,50,99,11,50,11,99,8,57,
    58,3,99,99,107,10,10,11,10,99,11,5,100,41,65,57,41,65,9,17,81,97,3,107,
    9,97,1,97,33,25,9,25,41,100,41,26,82,42,98,27,83,42,98,26,51,82,8,41,
    35,8,10,26,82,114,42,1,114,8,9,73,57,81,41,97,18,8,8,25,26,26,82,26,82,
    26,82,41,25,33,82,26,49,73,35,90,17,81,41,65,57,41,65,25,81,90,114,20,
    84,73,57,41,49,25,33,65,81,9,97,1,97,25,33,65,81,57,33,25,41,25,
};

static unsigned char stb_easy_font_vseg[253] = {
   4,2,8,10,15,8,15,33,8,15,8,73,82,73,57,41,82,10,82,18,66,10,21,29,1,65,
    27,8,27,9,65,8,10,50,97,74,66,42,10,21,57,41,29,25,14,81,73,57,26,8,8,
    26,66,3,8,8,15,19,21,90,58,26,18,66,18,105,89,28,74,17,8,73,57,26,21,
    8,42,41,42,8,28,22,8,8,30,7,8,8,26,66,21,7,8,8,29,7,7,21,8,8,8,59,7,8,
    8,15,29,8,8,14,7,57,43,10,82,7,7,25,42,25,15,7,25,41,15,21,105,105,29,
    7,57,57,26,21,105,73,97,89,28,97,7,57,58,26,82,18,57,57,74,8,30,6,8,8,
    14,3,58,90,58,11,7,74,43,74,15,2,82,2,42,75,42,10,67,57,41,10,7,2,42,
    74,106,15,2,35,8,8,29,7,8,8,59,35,51,8,8,15,35,30,35,8,8,30,7,8,8,60,
    36,8,45,7,7,36,8,43,8,44,21,8,8,44,35,8,8,43,23,8,8,43,35,8,8,31,21,15,
    20,8,8,28,18,58,89,58,26,21,89,73,89,29,20,8,8,30,7,
};

typedef struct
{
   unsigned char c[4];
} stb_easy_font_color;

static int stb_easy_font_draw_segs(float x, float y, unsigned char *segs, int num_segs, int vertical, stb_easy_font_color c, char *vbuf, int vbuf_size, int offset)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i < num_segs; ++i) {
        int len = segs[i] & 7;
        x += (float) ((segs[i] >> 3) & 1);
        if (len && offset+64 <= vbuf_size) {
            float y0 = y + (float) (segs[i]>>4);
            for (j=0; j < 4; ++j) {
                * (float *) (vbuf+offset+0) = x  + (j==1 || j==2 ? (vertical ? 1 : len) : 0);
                * (float *) (vbuf+offset+4) = y0 + (    j >= 2   ? (vertical ? len : 1) : 0);
                * (float *) (vbuf+offset+8) = 0.f;
                * (stb_easy_font_color *) (vbuf+offset+12) = c;
                offset += 16;
            }
        }
    }
    return offset;
}

static float stb_easy_font_spacing_val = 0;
static void stb_easy_font_spacing(float spacing)
{
   stb_easy_font_spacing_val = spacing;
}

static int stb_easy_font_print(float x, float y, char *text, unsigned char color[4], void *vertex_buffer, int vbuf_size)
{
    char *vbuf = (char *) vertex_buffer;
    float start_x = x;
    int offset = 0;

    stb_easy_font_color c = { 255,255,255,255 }; // use structure copying to avoid needing depending on memcpy()
    if (color) { c.c[0] = color[0]; c.c[1] = color[1]; c.c[2] = color[2]; c.c[3] = color[3]; }

    while (*text && offset < vbuf_size) {
        if (*text == '\n') {
            y += 12;
            x = start_x;
        } else {
            unsigned char advance = stb_easy_font_charinfo[*text-32].advance;
            float y_ch = advance & 16 ? y+1 : y;
            int h_seg, v_seg, num_h, num_v;
            h_seg = stb_easy_font_charinfo[*text-32  ].h_seg;
            v_seg = stb_easy_font_charinfo[*text-32  ].v_seg;
            num_h = stb_easy_font_charinfo[*text-32+1].h_seg - h_seg;
            num_v = stb_easy_font_charinfo[*text-32+1].v_seg - v_seg;
            offset = stb_easy_font_draw_segs(x, y_ch, &stb_easy_font_hseg[h_seg], num_h, 0, c, vbuf, vbuf_size, offset);
            offset = stb_easy_font_draw_segs(x, y_ch, &stb_easy_font_vseg[v_seg], num_v, 1, c, vbuf, vbuf_size, offset);
            x += advance & 15;
            x += stb_easy_font_spacing_val;
        }
        ++text;
    }
    return (unsigned) offset/64;
}

static int stb_easy_font_width(char *text)
{
    float len = 0;
    float max_len = 0;
    while (*text) {
        if (*text == '\n') {
            if (len > max_len) max_len = len;
            len = 0;
        } else {
            len += stb_easy_font_charinfo[*text-32].advance & 15;
            len += stb_easy_font_spacing_val;
        }
        ++text;
    }
    if (len > max_len) max_len = len;
    return (int) ceil(max_len);
}

static int stb_easy_font_height(char *text)
{
    float y = 0;
    int nonempty_line=0;
    while (*text) {
        if (*text == '\n') {
            y += 12;
            nonempty_line = 0;
        } else {
            nonempty_line = 1;
        }
        ++text;
    }
    return (int) ceil(y + (nonempty_line ? 12 : 0));
}
#endif

/*
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This software is available under 2 licenses -- choose whichever you prefer.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTERNATIVE A - MIT License
Copyright (c) 2017 Sean Barrett
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies
of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do
so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTERNATIVE B - Public Domain (www.unlicense.org)
This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or distribute this
software, either in source code form or as a compiled binary, for any purpose,
commercial or non-commercial, and by any means.
In jurisdictions that recognize copyright laws, the author or authors of this
software dedicate any and all copyright interest in the software to the public
domain. We make this dedication for the benefit of the public at large and to
the detriment of our heirs and successors. We intend this dedication to be an
overt act of relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to
this software under copyright law.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

Вот, тут у меня и происходят проблемы, вместо текста пустота.
надеюсь кто нибудь знает как это решить
и да, это проект OpenGL в codeblock

Comment: Anti Grain Geometry, Skia

Comment: а где другие проекты?_  Вам лень сделать нормальный вопрос с минимальным примером, а кто то должен отслеживать весь ваш проект?

Comment: Под какой кодировкой его подаёте? Каким шрифтом? В других программах этим шрифтом кириллица выводится? Имя гарнитуры в точности то же или как в 95-й винде, где латиница выводилась шрифтом Time New Roman, а кириллица – Time New Roman Cirilic, причём, Word переключал гарнитуру автоматически при смене языка?

Comment: если нужен GUI, то есть неплохая вещь https://tgui.eu

Answer (score 0):

В самой библиотеке указано следующее:

> Easy-to-deploy,
> reasonably compact,
> extremely inefficient performance-wise,
> crappy-looking,
> ASCII-only,
> bitmap font for use in 3D APIs.

Если упростить, то это костыль работающий только с ASCII. Соответственно ни о какой кириллице речи быть не может. Модернизировать библиотеку - плохая идея. Они сами пишут что это неэффективное решение. И менять подобное - это жуть. Просто вы вроде спрашиваете про подобную библиотеку. Лично я использую freetype в связке с fontconfig (для поиска шрифтов в системе). [Пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/441986/) использования. Для работы с кириллицей нужно передать char код буквы. Т.е. в UTF-16/UTF-32.

Просто другой момент - вы написали что это нужно для меню. Для этих целей оптимальнее использовать библиотеку GUI с возможностями работы с текстом. К примеру, один из наиболее популярных который я намерен использовать в дальнейшем ImGUI. Там текст идёт в UTF-8. И соответственно кириллица поддерживается.

А кстати ещё есть вопрос. Я ещё раз посмотрел ваш пост. Там же всё на WinAPI. Я вообще сторонник писать сразу кроссплатформенно. В WinAPI не особо силён. Но я видел пару проектов. Там через тот же WinAPI делаются контролы (кнопки, слайдеры и т.д.) и там же передаётся текст. Безо всяких библиотек. Вам не проще такой метод использовать?